# What is the benefit of using === operator to test for undefined instead of using == operator?

Tags: javascript

I usually test whether a JavaScript variable is defined or not, using the following test:

```
if (typeof a == 'undefined')
    a = 'default value'
```

However, I have seen many people suggesting that it is safer to use the following instead:

```
if (typeof a === 'undefined')
    a = 'default value'
```

I am aware of the difference between `==` and `===` operators but I am unable to understand why `typeof a == 'undefined'` could be unsafe.

Could you please a scenario in which the first code example is unsafe or could lead to issues? Also, what are the advantages of using the latter syntax over the first?

Comment: It's not unsafe. The `typeof` will always return a string, so their behavior will be identical.

Comment: There's no reason to choose the second on over the first one, other than being consistent.

Comment: I don't think it's going to make a difference with `undefined`.  There isn't any unexpected casting that would occur that would change the result.  `undefined` is as `undefined` does.

Comment: @user2736012 It's apparently based on uncertainty about `typeof` and the comparison operators. IMO that's a valid question.

Comment: @bfavaretto: We could make up uncertainties if we want. It would be a good question if there was some observable difference that OP had encountered.

Comment: I don't see how the question about == vs === is a duplicate of this question. My question is about whether `typeof foo == 'undefined'` could ever be problematic. This is a valid question with a valid answer, and the answer is "No".

Comment: It's not a duplicate. I don't know why @Ilya marked it. Though I wouldn't say it's a valid question. You're presuming a non-existant problem.

Comment: I agree, it's not a duplicate. Some people got carried away.

Comment: @user2736012 I think it's a valid question mainly because "`==` is evil" is repeated like a mantra on Stack Overflow; even Douglas Crockford doesn't see any reason for using it, *ever*. And an explanation of the cases when using `==` is fine is not as easy to find. You can only make your own conclusions about that if you're  familiar with the comparison algorithms described in the spec. I believe it's fine not to know that, and ask here. It's a question trying to understand something, and I tend to value that.

Comment: @bfavaretto I agree that this is a valuable question. However this "mantra" is based on valid arguments. Crocford is correct: although you can use `==` here, you can use `===` as well. This only proves Crocford's point. Also it proves that JS is badly designed. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I am unable to understand why `typeof a == 'undefined'` could be unsafe

It's not unsafe, it's perfectly fine. The `typeof` operator is [guaranteed to return a string](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.3), so you'll always be comparing two strings. The [abstract equality algorithm](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3) will behave just like [strict equality](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.6).

Answer (score 4):

Since `typeof a` is always a string then `==` and `===` will always yield the same result, i.e. there is no significant difference between them ( the only one is that one is longer then the other ;) ).

**Warning, personal opinion**: I find `==` operator completely horrible. How could anyone think that it is a good idea to have two different comparison operators? There is no other language where two objects of different type can be equal. This is insane. Thus people tend to use `===` all the time, because it is a good practice. So I guess that in this situation it is just a habit... a good habit.